# Converting different date formats. Which class?

Tags: r, date, type-conversion

I have several databases I want to merge based on several attributes.
For the merging, I am using the left_join function.

One struggle I always have is with converting different date formats before using the function.
I have both "YYYYMMDD" and "YYYYMM". The "DD" are always the last days of the respective month e.g. 2011-12-31 for YYYYMMDD and 201112 for YYYYMM.
As I think its too difficult to associate the last day of the month to every YYYYMM entry, I decided to use YYYYMM as my standard.
I struggle to get the YYYYMMDD converted into YYYYMM.

```
Dataset$Date <- as.double(Dataset$Date, format="%Y/%m")
```

Tried both as.date as well as as.double before using the code as well as different forms of the format. Code runs but the date still is 2011-12-31 rather than 201112.

Anything obvious I am missing?

Thanks and best,
D.

Comment: You probably are looking for `format` ? `Dataset$Date <- format(Dataset$Date, format="%Y/%m")`

Comment: The `lubridate` package offers great flexibility.